# Dynamically instantiating child classes with different constructor parameters in Python

Tags: python-2.7, oop, inheritance

Suppose I have a python 2.7 code which maintains a list of options. By parsing those options, the code can determine which child class of a complicated inheritance tree to instantiate next. However, the different child classes have different constructors which take different parameter numbers. So I find myself writing code like this:

```
childClassStr = get_child_class(currentOptionDict)
childClass = getattr(importlib.import_module("meow"), childClassStr)

# necessary parameters are all available at this point
if childClass == class1:
    classInstance = childClass(param3, param4)
elif childClass == class2:
    classInstance = childClass(param2, param3, param4)
else:
    classInstance = childClass(param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

I realize that this is most likely not a good way to handle this. Is there an accepted way of doing the instantiation? Should I dynamically build the parameter list to avoid the if else statements and write something like:

```
childClassStr = get_child_class(currentOptionDict)
childClass = getattr(importlib.import_module("meow"), childClassStr)
paramList = assemble_class_params(childClass)
classInstance = childClass(*paramList)
```

Or is there a cleaner way to do this? Each child class supports very different functionality; I put them in an inheritance tree to avoid duplicating methods shared between subsets of the child classes.